# How to change gorm.Record type to array

Tags: go, go-gorm

currently I am using **gorm** to retrieve data from db (postgresql db to be specific) and scan it in an `array`, the data stored in db is also in form of `array`. So problem I am facing is after scanning data in empty `int array` it changes into `gorm.Record` type which can't be used for basic array operation like, appending, iterating, etc.

Here's a related part of my code:

```
    var winner_selection []int64 // empty int64 array
    db.Table("giveaways").Select("Participants").Where("Name = ?", name).Scan(&winner_selection) // scanning the value in array
```

How can I retrieve the data directly in form of `array` so the `array` remains `array` or is there anyway to change `gorm.Record` type to array?